# Joomla Site not detecting https protocol

Tags: joomla-3.x, https

I have a Joomla site that I am finishing up and now loading onto the server that will host the live site. I'm now getting the following error in the javascript console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mydomain.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet

A view source reveals

```
<base href="http://mydomain.com"
```

This href value appears to be set in **/libraries/joomla/document/renderer/html/head.php**, which calls

```
$document->getBase()
```

to get this value. In **/libraries/joomla/document/document.php**, this value is set with an `$options` array passed to the constructor, but I cannot find where these options are set.

I had thought this value, as well as the constants `JPATH_BASE`, `JPATH_ROOT`, `JPATH_SITE`, etc., would be assigned whichever protocol the site uses. Am I missing a setting somewhere on the back end of the site?

I am using Joomla 3.7.2

Comment: Have you forced https using your Joomla global configuration, also this issue is generally due to some extension trying to load script using http, please find the css file that is loading using http, we could help you more with this information

Comment: Where is the CSS file being loaded from? Can you show us the code that's loading it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it really is the base href value that is causing the problem. Commenting out the assignment in `/libraries/joomla/document/renderer/html/head.php` will do the trick.

```
// Generate base tag (need to happen early)
/*
$base = $document->getBase();
if (!empty($base))
{
    $buffer .= $tab . '<base href="' . $base . '" />' . $lnEnd;
}
*/
```

However, it would be best to actually solve the problem of assigning the correct value. I found a better solution on StackOverflow here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733229/joomla-base-href-uses-http-instead-of-https

The accepted answer to this question tells us, "there servers where `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is obviously not initialized." So the real solution is to fix the .htaccess file, or as I did, the httpd.conf file by adding the following:

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
   SetEnv HTTPS on
</IfModule>
```

I suppose I could have kept searching before posting my question here, but by posting the answer perhaps I can save someone else the hours I spent yesterday on this problem.